# Is it possible to merge power of 4 pi 3 b+s on the OS level (Raspbian)

Tags: raspbian

Essentially, if I want to install a program that requires a certain amount of RAM that I don't have, can I use my 4 pis to merge RAM, etc.? I've tried cluster computing with MPIExec, which is fine, but now I want to do it on the OS level. Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: That would be very difficult to accomplish, and could result in system instability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to split general program's RAM requirements to quarters which is not possible.

You can use some tool (mpiexec) to process partial tasks (sort part of the array, convert part of the media stream) on distributed system, but you must bear in mind that each partial sub-task have access only to it's own RPI resources.

Comment: Too bad. If anyone comes up with a way to do it, hit me up